# Show UiAlertView if UILabel is Equal to empty

Tags: uilabel, uialertview

then in my app the user must enter data compulsorily.
Some of these data is controlled by NSInteger and some labels that take into account the click of a button displaying the number.

Now I need that when the user pushes the button "Save" if the label does not contain a number, a UIAlertView warns him of the missing field.

Below I have tried to do this .. With labels, you can use this system?

```
- (IBAction)FFSalvaDati_ConvalidaEsame:(id)sender {

    if (!FFVotazioneLabel == 0 || FFCFULabel  == 0) {
        UIAlertView *FFAlertConvalidaEsameError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ATTENZIONE" message:@"Per procedere con la convalidazione è necessario inserire il numero dei CFU ottenuti per questo esame e la sua Votazione. \n \n Senza questi dati non ci è possibile calcolare la tua media attuale!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [FFAlertConvalidaEsameError show];

    } else {


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the text of the label. Please consider checking again the code as I didn't test it myself. Do this:

```
- (IBAction)FFSalvaDati_ConvalidaEsame:(id)sender {

if ([FFVotazioneLabel.text isEqualToString:@""] || [FFCFULabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertView *FFAlertConvalidaEsameError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ATTENZIONE" message:@"Per procedere con la convalidazione è necessario inserire il numero dei CFU ottenuti per questo esame e la sua Votazione. \n \n Senza questi dati non ci è possibile calcolare la tua media attuale!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [FFAlertConvalidaEsameError show];

} else {


}
```